# A função não está retornando a variavel no html

Tags: javascript

```
<script>function calcular() {

        var d1 = document.getElementById('diametro1').value;
        var d2 = document.getElementById('diametro2').value;
        var w1 = 42,305 / Math.sqrt(d1) ;
        var w2 = 76,63 / Math.sqrt(d2) ;;

        document.getElementById('w1').innerHTML = "Resultado: "+parseFloat(w1.toFixed(8));
        document.getElementById('w2').innerHTML = "Resultado: "+parseFloat(w2.toFixed(8));

    }
</script>
```

Comment: Números em JavaScript não possuem vírgula.

Answer (score 2):

Há pelo menos dois erros de sintaxe nas seguintes linhas:

```
var w1 = 42,305 / Math.sqrt(d1) ;
var w2 = 76,63 / Math.sqrt(d2) ;;
```

- Primeiro: não utilizamos vírgula `,` para identificar números do tipo `float` em `JavaScript`. Para valores do tipo `float` utilizamos ponto `.`. Se o número for inteiro mesmo, deixe sem vírgula nem ponto, mesmo que seja maior que 999
- Segundo: não utilize o sinal de ponto e vírgula sem necessidade, como no seu código: `;;`